# Difference between all sub-combinations of array, the most efficient way

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, performance, time-complexity

We have an array list say [1, 2, 3, 4], I want the difference between all combinations, ie.
for [1, 2, 3, 4]  ->  1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3
that is (2-1), (3-2), (3-1), (4-3), (4-2) and (4-1)

I already made an inefficient code with high complexity. I need an efficient solution with less complexity in C++ or Python.

Answer (score 1):

Result size is `n*(n-1)/2`, where n is list size, so two for-loops solution is optimal one

```
for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(A)):
        diffs.append(A[j] - A[i])
```

Comment: Yes, I am using this currently, Cant this get any better?

Comment: No. As I said, we need to form result (as stated in the question) of described size

Comment: I wanted to ask another question on algorithm and Geometry but stackoverflow doesn't let me ask it. Can I ask you that question here? Please.

Comment: No, site rules allow only one question in the topic. I suppose you have to wait some time as new user (small reputation) to make new question.

Comment: no, i mean , ask question to you in the comments, if its fine by you? I just need an overview.

Comment: Yes if that question requires only short clue

Comment: This question is sub-part of ongoing Contest on Codechef, and answer to your question, Think Gematrically you can't simply reduce the number of pairs, its always gonna be O(N^2).

Comment: thanks!  We got 2 coordinates,  A- (a, b)   and B- (c, d)      we need to go from A to B, operations that we can perform are   (a+2b , b) or (a-2b, b) for left-right,  and   (a, b+2a) or (a, b-2a) for up-down...(if y < 0, we will add -ve sign to whole coordinate),  We need to count min. no. of steps to reach B, I am totally clueless how to proceed, any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code by using `itertools.combinations`, which is designed to to exactly what you're looking for.

`diffs = [y - x for x, y in itertools.combinations(list, 2)]`

There is probably some really complicated, clever algorithm that can do this in O(n log n), but any "normal" algorithm is going to have to look at each pair of elements, and there are n (n + 1) / 2 such pairs.

============== EDITED FOR LINEAR SOLUTION ====

Okay.  Just confirming that you're specifically asking for the difference, and not the absolute value of the difference in your solution.  If you're looking for their sum, rather than just the list, you can do some math.

Look at a list `[a, b, c, d]`.  You want
`(b - a) + (c - a) + (d - a) + (c - b) + (d - b) + (d-c)`
which simplifies to `-3*a - b + c + 3*d`

It's pretty easy to generalize and see that for a list of n elements, the multipliers are `-(n-1), -(n - 3), .... n-3, n-1` so you have

````
n = len(list)
sum(value * multiplier for value, multiplier in zip(list, range(-n+1, n, 2))```
````

Comment: could you simplify the last line please, with an example. say [1,2,3,4]. what should I write?